# Way of getting cities or major towns within specified route?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api, google-directions-api

Google Map Direction API can provide an optimized route when we supply it start point, end point & way-points in between. My requirement is to get important places (i.e. cities, major towns), that come in between the start point & end point I am going to provide. Does Google Maps Direction API provides this kind of information ? Or currently there is no way to get this info from Google Map.

```
Input (I am going to give): start point & end point,

Output route ( I am expecting from Google Map API) : start point, x1-point, x2-point, x3-point.... end point,
```

So I am expecting all the x points from google which must be the cities, major towns that are in-between the start & end point.

Comment: There is something that is not clear. Are you perhaps the one who's going to provide those places or are you expecting places returned from google servers? There seems to be a conflict in your question :)

Comment: @pcj, I have to same implementation as this question, so if you have answer of your question ya any suggestion please give me.

Answer (score 0):

The "important places" that you are referring to is a vague category and is not contained in the [types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponseElements) parameter which categorizes the places in Directions API. You may put [waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints) which specifies a particular location on your map in which you will be routed before reaching the endpoint(click here for the [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints)). You will be the one to choose and research which are the major towns and cities as points. Then, manually set those as waypoints.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I understand the "important places" is a vague category. Lets eliminate the "important places". So think of this case I have a route X-Y-Z, where X= start , Y=Waypoint, Z=end. Lets limit the "important places" to cities, towns. So can we get cities, towns that are on this route X-Y-Z ?